# __str__ и список

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

У меня есть класс:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.n)
```

и список `arr`, в котором лежат экземпляры класса:

```
arr = [MyClass(0), MyClass(1)]
```

как сделать так чтобы при `print(arr)` выводилось:

```
['0', '1']
```

а не:

```
[<__main__.MyClass object at 0xebeb3dc0>, <__main__.MyClass object at 0xebdcb580>]
```

полный код:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.n)

arr = [MyClass(0), MyClass(1)]

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Добавьте реализацию специального метода `__repr__`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.n)
```

Comment: Тогда уж `return repr(self.n)`